# VBA excel: Filtering By date and assigning Criteria2 value to a variable?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, filter, criteria

I have a table with a column that has dates I am filtering through. I am trying to take the criteria value and assign it to a variable but keep running into an error. (Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error).
Can anyone help?

filter code:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MyTbl").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(0, "10/1/2017")
```

My Code:

```
Dim x As Variant

If Table.AutoFilter.Filters(5).On Then

    x = Table.AutoFilter.Filters(5).Criteria2
    
End If
```

Comment: there is no Criteria1? I'm trying to set my x variable to the value of Criteria2 when I filter a column in a table containing dates.

Comment: I am not setting it to Criteria2. It is a recorded macro

Comment: When Filtering a Column of dates, Excel uses Criteria2 not Criteria1 by default

Comment: I already did. Criteria1 doesn't exist

Comment: Posted an answer. See if it helps now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim lo As ListObject ' optional declaration
Set lo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MyTbl") ' optional variable assignment

If Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
     ActiveSheet.Range("MyTbl").AutoFilter
End If

With lo.Range
    .AutoFilter Field:=5, _ 
    Operator:=xlFilterValues, _ 
    Criteria2:=Array(0, "10/1/2017")
End With
```

Comment: I'm not trying to filter. After a column of dates in a table is filtered, I am trying to take the value that has been filtered, Criteria2, and assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying?

Let's say our data looks like this

[image]

My table name is `Table1` and it is in `Sheet1`. Change the below code as applicable.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Table As ListObject
    
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim Ar(1 To 3) As Date
    
    Ar(1) = DateSerial(2017, 1, 10)
    Ar(2) = DateSerial(2017, 2, 13)
    Ar(3) = DateSerial(2017, 2, 15)
    
    Set ws = Sheet1
    Set Table = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    
    With Table
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=Ar
         
         x = Join(Table.AutoFilter.Filters(5).Criteria1, ",")
         
         MsgBox x
    End With
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]

Comment: I think this is flipped from what I am trying to do. I am not trying to filter a table based on  criteria. I am trying to filter a table then take the criteria that was used to filter and assign it to a variable.

Comment: No. I think you have misunderstood. `I am trying to filter a table then take the criteria that was used to filter and assign it to a variable. –` This is exactly what my code is also doing. My suggestion is not to use the code given by macro recorder to filter but use the code that I gave you above to filter. Once you filter using my code then you will be able to store the criteria value to a variable.